# Update value of a "Field" based on some selection on different screen

Tags: react-native, redux-form, react-native-navigation

#### Problem:

I am trying to update the value of a redux-form field based of some selection on a different screen from where the field is.

What I am doing is:

1) Show a form with a `TouchableOpacity`. It is given the styling of a dropdown (this is the `registeredField`)

2) Click on that button and you get redirected to a list view

3) Click on one item from the list

4) You are redirected back

5) The placeholder should change to the selection done on the previous screen

---

What happens is:

If I click on the dropdown (touchable opacity button) directly and come back the value doesn't get updated. But as soon as I change input for any of the other fields - the label changes immediately. The same also works if I have something in one of the other inputs and then I do the selection - the label changes as expected.

#### My Attempt:

To show the label what I am doing is preparing an `initialValues` object and passing it down to the component which renders the form in order to show the label appropriately:

#### The field component:

```
....
<TouchableOpacity onPress={openPicker}>
  <Text>{groupName || 'Select Group'}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
....
```

#### The form field within a `reduxForm` connected component:

```
<Field
    name="groupName"
    placeholder="Group"
    groupPicker // to render the picker or a normal input box
    groupName={groupName} // the value used as placeholder
    openGroupPicker={openGroupPicker}
    component={FormInput}
 />
 ....
 const connectedDriverForm = reduxForm({
    form: 'driverForm',
    validate,
    enableReinitialize: true,
 })(DriverForm);
```

#### The form within the container where the `initialvalues` prop is passed:

```
const {
  subhaulerPhone,
  subhaulerEmail,
  groupName,
} = this.props;
const initialValues = {
  subhaulerPhone,
  subhaulerEmail,
  groupName,
};
// within render()
<DriverForm
    initialValues={initialValues}
    openGroupPicker={this.handleOpenGroupPicker}
    onDriverFormSubmit={this.handleDriverFormSubmit}
    onCancel={this.closeDriverForm}
/>
```

I tried to tap into the `change` event of redux-form:

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {
    ...mapDispatchToProps,
    saveGroupName: groupName => change('driverForm', 'groupName', groupName),
  },
)(UserManagementForm);
```

---

I used the `initialValues` prop so that the picker shows proper label on selection and also loads and saves the form properly whenever the screen is changed.

I have an action to save the form values and to set the group name:

```
import { pathOr } from 'ramda';
import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect';
import {
  initialState,
  SAVE_FORM_VALUES,
  SET_GROUP_NAME,
  CLEAR_GROUP_NAME,
  CLEAR_FORM_VALUES,
} from './usermanagementform.constants';

export const userManagementFormSelector = createStructuredSelector({
  subhaulerPhone: pathOr('', ['userManagementForm', 'subhaulerPhone']),
  subhaulerEmail: pathOr('', ['userManagementForm', 'subhaulerEmail']),
  groupName: pathOr('', ['userManagementForm', 'groupName']),
  subhaulerFormValues: pathOr({}, ['form', 'driverForm', 'values']),
});

export const userManagementFormReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SAVE_FORM_VALUES:
      return {
        ...state,
        ...action.data,
      };
    case CLEAR_FORM_VALUES:
      return {
        subhaulerPhone: '',
        subhaulerEmail: '',
        groupName: '',
      };
    case SET_GROUP_NAME:
      return {
        ...state,
        groupName: action.groupName,
      };
    case CLEAR_GROUP_NAME:
      return {
        ...state,
        groupName: '',
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

---

All my attempts have been futile so far. This is an edge case, and I cannot seem to understand why this doesn't work or what doesn't work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Resource Used:

- https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/2496
- [Redux-Form update field value from external interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41809474/redux-form-update-field-value-from-external-interaction)
- https://redux-form.com/7.1.2/docs/api/actioncreators.md/