# Set a field value directly from an asyncValidate result

Tags: redux-form, react-redux-form

I have a form where a user enters an Id into a text field, and I then I validate said Id on the server. If the Id does not exist in the system, I display an error. I do this using `async` validation. If the Id does exist, however, the server will return a record from our database. I want to use those values to auto populate other fields in the form.

How would I accomplish this?

I did some searching and the closest solution I found was [this other question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41809474/redux-form-update-field-value-from-external-interaction). The thing is, I want to change the value after my `asycValidate` logic has succeeded. I don't think I can trigger the action creator from inside `asyncValidate`, and I'm not aware of a way to have `asyncValidate` trigger a callback from inside the form component.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work, by following the solutions discussed in the following thread: https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/442